# What is WHY (when thinking of DRY)?

Tags: oop

I'm learning how to code, and I'm reading notes for what OOP is, written by a teacher, and he mentions WHY (but doesn't explain it). I've worked out easier ones like CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

I'm an online student, and every time I ask a question (of the school) it either takes ages to get a response, I'm lost in translation, or both.

I've tried searching for it, but WHY is far to common a term. Is WHY even something to do with OOP, or is it an accidental capitalisation?

So what is WHY? Do you know of any articles, or content on WHY (and other things like this I'm bound to come across)?

Thx.

Comment: Never heard of it myself. Is it really an acronym?

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think the same. This teacher thinks he's pretty hip, so maybe it's one of his.